# Performance of "left join" in F#

Tags: performance, csv, f#-data

I'm essentially trying to perform an sql left join in F# taking in two csv-files and producing a third. My files are not huge (around 200k rows) but I still experience horrific performance - in fact it is faster using vlookup in xl...

The csv's both have an identifier "column" which holds compatible values but a value present in one csv is not guaranteed to be in the other.

I have tinkered with it, and I suspect the search through one csv for every row in the other is the killer.

**EDIT: Replacing Array with Map improves performance a lot. But I guess this can still be improved further**

Any ideas for improving this?

Some (pseudo) code:

```
open FSharp.Data

type DataLeft = 
    CsvProvider<Sample = "identifier;var1;var2", AssumeMissingValues = true, Schema = "identifier (string), var1, var2", Separators=";", HasHeaders=true, Encoding="UTF-8">

type DataRight = 
    CsvProvider<Sample = "identifier;var3;var4", AssumeMissingValues = true, Schema = "identifier (string), var3 (float option), var4 (float option)", Separators=";", HasHeaders=true, Encoding="UTF-8">

type Output =
    CsvProvider<Sample = "identifier;var1;var2;var3;var4", AssumeMissingValues = true, Schema = "identifier (string), var1, var2, var3 (float option), var4 (float option)", Separators=";", HasHeaders=true, Encoding="UTF-8">

let leftRows = DataLeft.Load(leftPath).Rows

// (slightly) more efficient to convert to array
let rightRows = DataRight.Load(rightPath).Rows |> Seq.toArray
**EDIT: let rightRows = DataRight.Load(rightPath).Rows |> Seq.map (fun row -> (row.Identifier, row)) |> Map.ofSeq**

let getMissingVars (row : DataLeft.Row) =
    let id = row.Identifier
    let rightRow = rightRows |> Array.tryFind (fun rRow -> rRow.Identifier = id)
**EDIT: let rightRow = rightRows.TryFind(id)**
    match rightRow with
    | None ->
        Output.Row(
            id,
            row.Var1,
            row.Var2,
            None,
            None)
    | Some realRow -> 
        Output.Row(
            id,
            row.Var1,
            row.Var2,
            realRow.Var3,
            realRow.Var4)

let rows = leftRows |> Seq.map getMissingVars

let csv = new Output(rows)
csv.Save(path = "outputPath")
```

Comment: I should have added that the identifier uniquely determines a row in both csv-files. 
I did consider thinning out the rightRows as we go since if an identifier from leftRows are found in rightRows, it will not occur again. Not sure that this will ultimately make anything faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply creating a dictionary for lookups solved the issue. I gave up trying to improve further, so posting this as answer.

As per edit replace

```
let rightRows = DataRight.Load(rightPath).Rows |> Seq.toArray
```

with

```
let rightRows = 
    DataRight.Load(rightPath).Rows 
    |> Seq.map (fun row -> (row.Identifier, row)) 
    |> Map.ofSeq
```

or some nicer dictionary. Then replace `Array.tryFind` with `Map.tryFind`